# Synchronized lock by particular ID

Tags: java, synchronized

I have a REST API which has one method M which does something.
Of course it's called by multiple threads sometimes simultaneously.
This method M has an input String `businessID`
(which comes from the payload of the caller/client).

Now... I want to protect one particular section from method M's body against simultaneous execution by multiple threads. But I want to defend it **only if** I have simultaneous executions by two threads T1 and T2 for the **same** `businessID` value. So after some thinking I decided to go with this approach.

```
public M(){ 
    
    // non-critical work 1 
    
    String bid = businessID.intern();
    synchronized (bid){
        // do some critical work here 
    }
    
    // non-critical work 2 
    
}
```

That means I intend to use **the interned version** of the String `businessID` as a lock to my critical section of code.

Is this going to work as intended? I think so... but I want to be absolutely sure.

Also, does anyone have any alternative ideas how to implement this? I wonder if there's some ready-made solution, like an idiomatic way of doing this in Java, without having to implement my own cache, my own eviction mechanism, etc. etc.

*Note that delays caused by this synchronization are not worrying me. It is very rare scenario two threads to call the method M with the same business ID at the same tome (happens only once or twice per day). Also the critical section takes no more than 1-2 secs to complete execution. So delays caused by threads waiting for obtaining the lock, this is not worrying me here.*

Comment: Maybe you can use a map of lock objects accessed by the business id as a key?

Comment: @voyager42 That was my original plan A but it quickly gets complicated, and it's much more error-prone. Also, some background thread needs to clean up that map every N minutes or so. It's not so easy, I tried it. So as a plan B, if I can just lock on this `bid` variable, that solves all my issues.

Comment: @peter.petrov no you can't, because you don't lock on the "value", you lock on the reference to the string. voyager42's suggestion is the way to go, and frankly its not very complicated ;)

Comment: @TomElias I can't what? Of course I lock on the reference but there will be exactly one reference per business ID value, no?

Comment: @peter.petrov its even worse than that! you won't lock anything because Strings are immutable and your variable isnt shared between threads. you need a static map of string to ReentrantLock.

Comment: "bid" is a local variable of the method you are running. it is not shared between threads. the other threads "see" a different address in memory of the "bid" variable, so each thread will only lock it's "own" bid variable. you need a static member that is shared across all the JVM in order for other threads to access it.

Comment: are you retrieving/constructing a business object based on businessID, before starting the critical section?

Comment: @TomElias Consider `String  test1 = "test1".intern();
          String  test2 = "test1".intern();
          
          System.out.println(test1.hashCode());
          System.out.println(test2.hashCode());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bad idea because:

1. String#intern() is a native method and it uses native Hash Table which apparently is [much slower](https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/10-string-intern/) than a typical ConcurrentHashMap.
2. You probably don't want the pool of strings to grow indefinitely. How would you invalidate entries from there?

I think using your own map of strings will be the preferred way. Maybe Guava's cache could be leveraged because you need to evict items from that map eventually. But this needs further research.

#### Leasing a lock

Another option is to have a set of predefined lock objects. E.g. a HashMap of size 513. Then to acquire a lock use `bid.hashCode() mod 513`:

```
int hash = Math.abs(bid.hashCode() % 513);
Object lock = locks.get(hash);
synchronized(lock) {...}
```

This will occasionally lock unrelated transactions, but at least you don't have to bother with eviction.

PS: there was some method to calculate a true `mod` in Math class.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that eviction is what makes things complicated. Then questions come up like... how do you make sure you evict something only when it's not used for locking, etc. etc.

Comment: "You probably don't want the pool of strings to grow indefinitely" >>> Yes, I don't know how I missed that "minor detail" :)

Comment: I wonder if there's some ready-made solution, like an idiomatic way of doing this in Java without having to implement my own cache, my own eviction mechanism, etc. etc.

Comment: I don't know any idiomatic ways, but what if you had a set of lock objects (let's say 512) and you'd take `bid.hashCode() mod 512` and use that object as a lock? You may sometimes get 2 unrelated transactions locked, but at least you won't have to worry about eviction.

Comment: Yet another alternative is a lock on DB level (either `select for update` if the row exists, or something like advisory locks in PG: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html). It's gong to be slower, but it's a ready-to-go mechanism and it will work even if you have multiple instances of the app running.

Comment: Ah, that with the mod 512 seems like a very smart idea. Thank you. I think I'll just go for that because... anyway, I get only 80-90 calls to that method M per day. So I don't care that much, in fact I could have just used a global lock object but I didn't want to go for that, it's just too dumb.

Comment: Ok, I'll add that to the answer. And I just realiazed that DB-level locks will not help with happens-before behaviour - it's just a way of ordering operations.

Comment: Having a `ConcurrentHashMap<String,Object> LOCK`, you can simply use `LOCK.computeIfAbsent(businessID, key -> { /* do some critical work here  */ return null;});` by returning `null`, the entry will be removed immediately after the critical work has been done. In fact, from the `Map` interface’s perspective, the entry never existed.

Comment: @Holger, yep, that looks even better!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can maintain a registry of current locks held by each businessId and before starting critical section, peek into this registry to get/create a lock and after you are done with critical section , release the lock.

Well, It's not production ready something like below

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

```
class Lock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String businessId ="bid1";
        Lock lock = getLockObjectForBusinessId(businessId);
       
        synchronized (lock) {
            //critical section start
            //do work
            //critical section end
            releaseLockForBusinessId(businessId);
        }

    }

    public static Map<String, Lock> currentLocks = new HashMap<>();

   public static synchronized Lock getLockObjectForBusinessId(String businessId){

       Lock currentLock = currentLocks.get(businessId);
       if(currentLock==null){
           Lock lock = new Lock();
           currentLocks.put(businessId,lock);
           return  lock;
       }
       else{
           return currentLock;
       }
    }

    public static synchronized  void releaseLockForBusinessId(String businessId){
        currentLocks.remove(businessId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know, I can do that. But then additional complexities arise. How do you evict objects from that registry and when, and how do you make sure you don't evict something while it's in use? I wanted to avoid all these complexities, that's how this idea with the `intern` came up.

Comment: well in the above impl, acquire and release both are synchronized on class instance (static), so you don't need to worry about that .